Movie about people on nude beach
I remember this old movie I saw on TV like 10 years ago. It was probably from the 80s or early 90s.
It was a movie set on a nude beach.  From what I remember, it had nudity, both male and female. The movie was in english, might've been british, but I feel like they were on a nude beach on vacation, possibly in spain but I'm not sure.  I don't remember any known actors in it.
I remember there being an old man that young attractive women were teasing and I feel like he eventually got something out of it.
I also remember a key line when a larger naked woman talks about how her boyfriend put superglue on his penis before they had sex and it got stuck inside her and she kept on hitting him until the cops/paramdeics had to come to separate them.
Been looking for this for years, Any help would be great

Could this be Maslin Beach (1997)?

Set on a famous nudist beach, Maslin Beach is a film about crazy
people involved in crazy misunderstandings and romantic squabbles, a
naked and hilarious search for the meaning of life. And it’s also a
gentle story about love. Simon attempts to summon the courage to face
the truth about his relationship with Marcie over the course of one
afternoon, leading to a bittersweet jolt to his life. With other
relationships on the beach interfering with his objective to propose,
a myriad of characters attempt to make sense of life, love and it all.

One of the vignettes contains a monologue about a girl who superglues herself to her boyfriend.

Usually nudist films tend to avoid the topic of sex altogether, the
romance is chaste and innocent, but here a woman talking about her ex
putting superglue on his penis before sex so that they'd be together
forever

Warning: NSFW (Nudity)



